# How to clear text fields when returning back to a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to clear the text fields on the form once it's in focus again. Here is my code for the form in which I want to clear the text fields named `user_textbox` and `pwd_textbox`

```
namespace RDASMS
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            user_textbox.Clear();
            pwd_textbox.Clear();
        }

        private void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registration newuser = new Registration();
            newuser.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void submit_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int checkuser = string.CompareOrdinal(user_textbox.Text, "Admin");
            if (checkuser == 0)
            {
                int checkpwd = string.CompareOrdinal(pwd_textbox.Text, "rnsit123");
                if (checkpwd == 0)
                {
                    Admin newuser = new Admin();
                    newuser.RefToLogin = this;
                    newuser.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) - What problem have you run into?

Comment: How do you get back to the main form? You only show the code that hides the main and brings another form to the foreground.

Comment: well, there's no need to `Clear()` them in the constructor. The textboxes are _created_ in the `InitializeComponent()` method. Have you looked at [when a Form gets focus and what potential events  are triggered then](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the Form.Activated event to handle this, when activated clear out your textboxes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx

you can put some code like this :

```
foreach (Control c in yourForm.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `Hide` on your Form, which is equal to setting `Visible` to `false`, you can use the event [VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) of the Form to clear your TextFields.

```
private void Form_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if (this.Visible == true) {
    user_textbox.Clear();
    pwd_textbox.Clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Form Activated to determine if the form has come back into focus.